# Improving redux reducers

Tags: redux

For the Redux reducer code below (pay attention on the `UPDATE_TASK` action and the `updateTask` reducer function mainly), I keep a single `project` on my state object. This `project` has multiple `milestones`, that by its turn has multiple `tasks`.

When I update a given task, I am triggering the `UPDATE_TASK` action. It will then perform a `PUT` request, and receive the updated version of the `task` as the payload.

Next, I iterate through all the `milestones` of the `project` object from my state. If it matches the task's `milestone_id`, I then proceed to iterate through all of the `tasks` of that milestone, building a collection that contains all the previous tasks, replacing the one I got from the response.

Is this the best way to approach building the modified state using Redux? Also, is it advised to extract functions for non-trivial state updates like I am doing? What could be improved in my code (either stylistic or any ES6 tricks I am not aware of)?

```
import { FETCH_PROJECT } from '../actions/index';
import { FETCH_PROJECTS } from '../actions/index';
import { FETCH_MILESTONES } from '../actions/index';
import { FETCH_TASKS } from '../actions/index';
import { UPDATE_TASK } from '../actions/index';

const INITIAL_STATE = { all: [], project: null, milestones: [] };

// injects a collection of tasks on the milestone that
// matches the id we're using to fetch
function updateTasks(state, action) {
  const milestones = state.project.milestones.map((milestone) => {
    if (milestone.id == action.meta.id) {
      return { ...milestone, tasks: action.payload.data.tasks }
    }
    return milestone;
  });
  const project = { ...state.project, milestones };

  return { ...state, project };
}

// updates a single task on the proper milestone
function updateTask(state, action) {
  const { task } = action.payload.data;
  const milestones = state.project.milestones.map((milestone) => {
    if (milestone.id == task.milestone_id) {
      const tasks = milestone.tasks.map((milestoneTask) => {
        if (milestoneTask.id == task.id) {
          return task;
        }
        return milestoneTask;
      });

      return { ...milestone, tasks: tasks };
    }
    return milestone;
  });
  const project = { ...state.project, milestones };

  return { ...state, project };
}

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_PROJECT:
      return { ...state, project: action.payload.data.project };

    case FETCH_PROJECTS:
      return { ...state, all: action.payload.data.projects };

    case FETCH_MILESTONES:
      return { ...state, milestones: action.payload.data.milestones };

    case FETCH_TASKS:
      return updateTasks(state, action);

    case UPDATE_TASK:
      return updateTask(state, action);
  }

  return state;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You build your reducers around what type of actions you perform. A better way would be to build your reducers around the data the state contains.

Hence, take a good look at your initial state:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { all: [], project: null, milestones: [] };
```

you can create a separate reducer for each of them. Something like this could work.

```
function projects(state={}, action) {
    case FETCH_PROJECTS:
        return action.payload.data.projects
    ...etc
}

function activeProject(state={}, action) {
    case FETCH_PROJECT:
        return action.payload.data.project
    case FETCH_MILESTONES:
        // add milestone to appropriate project
}

function milestones(state={}, action) {
    case FETCH_MILESTONES:
        // add milestone
    case FETCH_TASKS:
         // add task to appropriate milestone

}

function tasks(state={}, action) {
    case FETCH_TASKS:
        // update appropriate task
}
```

Then later you can combine all these reducers using [combineReducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html), or you combine them yourself.

To get some help in structuring your date, take a look at https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr. The idea is to keep your data represented as flatly as possible in your reducers. This way you don't need nested reducers and you avoid complexity.

In your example, every milestone could have a list of tasks creating a object like this:

```
{
   m1: { tasks: [t1,t2], ...}
   m2: { tasks: [t3], ...}
   m3: { tasks: [t4,t5], ...}
}
```

And your tasks could be an object mapping ids to their contents like:

```
{
   t1: {} //task 
   t2: {} //task 
   t3: {} //task 
   t4: {} //task 
   t5: {} //task 
}
```

And the same thing for projects and milestones, relating them in the same way.